# How do I prevent access to an add-on domain's root directory from main hosting domain name

Tags: domains, cpanel

I have an add-on domain in my cPanel website. The root directory for it is under the root of the hosting. How can I prevent access through the main domain?

For example, `addondomain.com` is configured to serve up files from `public_html/addondomdain`. How do I prevent people seeing the files at `maindomain.com/addondomain` and only when viewing them at `addondomain.com`?

Comment: Hmm, I was using subdomain but the hosting company could not get the certificate working.  They told me to use and addon domain.  Now the certificate works, but I have your problem.  Arrghhh...  Not only that, "/img/x" is different to "img/x".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rewrite rule (in `public_html/addondomain/.htaccess`) will handle redirection for you, should a visitor land at a `domain.com/addondomain/` path:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}       !addondomain\.com$
RewriteRule [addondomain]?(.*) http://www.addondomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The rewrite condition instructs mod_rewrite to match on requests where the requested domain name does *not* end in "addondomain.com" (to include the primary domain and all its subdomains) and the rule instructs mod_rewrite to remove the `addondomain` subdirectory from the request path (if it appears) and direct the user to the add-on domain name.

Comment: I'm having the hardest time with this.  It works when only the directory is in the URL (`domain.com/addondomain/`).  However, as soon as I add a filename to the URL, it simply loads the specified page (`domain.com/addondomain/index.html`).  I've tried dozens of solutions and wonder if there is something within cPanel that the host is using to override my rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide the addon domain subfolder on your root domain, as it is literally a directory on your website root. You can use an htaccess rule to prevent people accessing it, or you can simply forward it to the subdomain.

Comment: Can you please give an example of a rule that would do that then?

Comment: On second thoughts, preventing access to the subfolder altogether would most probably prevent access to the addon domain also. I think your best bet is to do a redirect from within cPanel.